# JavaFX: How to unregister Button Action Event

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Button which sets an action like

```
moveRight.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
}});
```

How can I remove this EventFilter from that Button? I tried `removeEventHandler` method but what should be the parameters for that?

Comment: if you just want to remove it, you can set moveRight.setOnAction(null),
to remove specific handler you have to keep a reference for it.

Comment: and possiably if i want to ragister it again then what to do...

Comment: then you have to create eventhandler like this:
'EventHandler<ActionEvent> eh = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {//Code};

button.setOnAction(eh); //add
button.removeOnAction(eh); //remove '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment under your question is barely legible, I'm posting an answer.

Based on your comments you want to register an actionlistener, remove it, the reregister the same listener.

There are more then on ways to accomplish this.

1) Write your own handler:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> eh = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // CODE
    }
};
button.setOnAction(eh); //registered
button.setOnAction(null); //unregistered
button.setOnAction(eh); //re-registered
```

(Same with lamda looks like this:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> eh = (ActionEvent event) -> {
                // CODE
            };
```

)

2) Make your class implement EventHandler and override the abstract methods. Then you can add/remove listener by:

```
button.setOnAction(this);
button.removeEventHandler(ActionEvent.Action,this);
```

In the handle method you can get the object that was calling your method, by event.getSource() so you can get your button back in the handle method by

```
Button b = (Button)event.getSource();
```

3) Create some other class that is implementing javafx.event.EventHandler and instantiate that as your handler;

Answer (score 3):

The following call does the trick you want:

```
moveRight.setOnAction(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well disable it from being clicked and it does not listen to action anymore